# Why am I getting insanely high values for left value of position()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, game-physics

The relevant piece of code is

```
    this.place = function ()
    {
        var headElem = game.snake.links[0];
        this.bub.css({
            left: headElem.pos.x * game.blockWidth + $('#snake-board-column').css('padding-left'),
            bottom: headElem.pos.y * game.blockWidth
        });
        console.log(this.bub.position()); // TEST
    }
```

and the intent of it is to make a word bubble position relative to an SVG `rect` element (If you're wondering why I don't simply use CSS, it's because there's a lot of swapping/replacing of elements due to the game logic). The above function is invoked on page load and when the window resizes. What I'm finding strange is that the result of my test

```
console.log(this.bub.position()); // TEST
```

is sometimes producing very high values for `left` when the window is resized, and as a result the word bubble is off the screen. I just resized the window and got

```
Objectleft: 308.5top: 0__proto__: Object
game.js:290 Objectleft: 23515top: 0__proto__: Object
game.js:290 Object {top: 0, left: 23515}
game.js:290 Object {top: 0, left: 23515}
game.js:290 Object {top: 0, left: 23515}
game.js:290 Object {top: 0, left: 23515}
game.js:290 Object {top: 0, left: 23515}
game.js:290 Object {top: 0, left: 23515}
game.js:290 Object {top: 0, left: 23515}
game.js:290 Object {top: 0, left: 169169}
game.js:290 Object {top: 0, left: 169169}
game.js:290 Object {top: 0, left: 169169}
```

where you can see the first value for `left` is `308.5` (normal, expected) and the subsequent values are out of whack. You can see it in action [here](http://playclassicsnake.com/Play) and the full JS [here](https://github.com/jamkin/Snake/blob/master/SnakeGame/Scripts/game.js). Any idea what is causing this nonsense????

The strangest thing is that I've tested the individual values

`headElem.pos.x`, `game.blockWidth` and `$('#snake-board-column').css('padding-left')` and they all seem normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be concatenating strings instead of adding integers.

What is the type of `headElem.pos.x`, `game.blockWidth` and `$('#snake-board-column').css('padding-left')`?

For example, I tried this in the console:

```
var paddingLeft = $('#snake-board-column').css('padding-left');
>> typeof paddingLeft
>> 'string'
```

Try `parseInt()` before summing the values.

Comment: `typeof headElem.pos.x = number
game.js:301 typeof game.blockWidth = number
game.js:302 $('#snake-board-column').css('padding-left') = string`